# Android: How to move the cursor down to next line in the multiline Edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a requirement where i have to implement Buttons which can move the cursor up and down the line in a multi line Edittext.

I went through the Developer website and found that Selection class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html
can be used, but i am not able to use it..

Please help me here..

Thank you.

Comment: try EditText's public void setSelection (int index)

Comment: setSelection (int index) - using this i can move cursor to end and at the beginning of the edittext but how can i move it to next line in a multiline EditText ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804670/edittext-line-number-and-currentline-cursor-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/text/Selection.java

I copied the code and made a little modification below, then appended it to my class.

---

```
public boolean moveDown(Layout layout) {
        int start = myTextbox.getSelectionStart();
        int end = myTextbox.getSelectionEnd();

        if (start != end) {
            int min = Math.min(start, end);
            int max = Math.max(start, end);

            myTextbox.setSelection(max);

            if (min == 0 && max == myTextbox.length()) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            int line = layout.getLineForOffset(end);

            if (line < layout.getLineCount() - 1) {
                int move;

                if (layout.getParagraphDirection(line) ==
                    layout.getParagraphDirection(line + 1)) {
                    float h = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(end);
                    move = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line + 1, h);
                } else {
                    move = layout.getLineStart(line + 1);
                }

                myTextbox.setSelection(move);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I hope this will be useful.

If somebody knows how to use real method without recreating it, please share :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this code but it may help you to some extend....

just go through the code from the following url. i might help you to find out solution.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/text/Selection.java

Comment: I have seen this, but did not understand how to use it. I am confused!! Mainly How do i initialize this class? and what do i write in the parameters of **moveDown(Spannable text, Layout layout)** method?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

editText.append("\n");

It will move cursor to next line.