# Finding End of Line of an EditText

Tags: java, android

I have a multi-line EditText box in Android Studio and some buttons that can direct the cursor to different places in the text (i.e. beginning of the text, end of text, beginning of a line, or end of line); however, the beginning/end or a line buttons, send me to the beginning and ending of the text respectively, and not the lines.

I went through the debugger and discovered that even if the text reaches the end of a line and begins on the next line, a "\n" is not added to the string, though it reaches the next line of the text box.

So, how can I move the cursor to the  beginning and end of a line when I can search for the new line character?

Comment: Could you manage to get the index of the line in the EditText?

Comment: The answer below gives a way to do that. On posting this question, I didn't know how to do that. I've only been using Android Studio for a few weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get the line index on which the cursor lies. I am including that code but you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804670/edittext-line-number-and-currentline-cursor-position).

```
val lineIndex = getCursorLinePosition( editText ) 

val startPos = editText.layout.getLineStart( lineIndex )
// for beginning for a line
editText.setSelection( startPos )

val endPos = editText.layout.getLineEnd( lineIndex )
// for end of the line
editText.setSelection( endPos )
```

Comment: Is the `getCursorLinePosition` function the function used in the link you put in the answer?

Comment: Yes. Including that function would have created confusion and therefore I have included it in the given link